# request header details sent from client to server using PHP

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers

How to get request header details which client send to server like the URL + cookie + postdata + other stuff

Comment: where do you want to "get" them ? on server logs ? live on the browser ? what have you done until now ?

Answer (score 0):

Check $_SERVER variable, it contains all information you need.

Comment: No, getallheaders doesn't work with nginx, it needs to be shimmed.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Thanks for pointing it out, I did not notice tags of this post. I have updated my answer based on your response